# Caret position changing in input element Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, caret

I have an input element with a max length of 12, and I am trying to clear the middle element from it but the caret position is automatically going to the end even if I am trying to clear the middle element. Have attached a stackblitz link [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-welcome-app-jitrxn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: why are you removing the last digit on removing the digit from middle? the last digit get's removed and cursor moves to end.
`this.unmaskedInput = this.unmaskedInput.slice(0, -1);`
`this.rawInput = this.rawInput.slice(0, -1);`

Comment: thank you for replying! , can you provide info on how i should tackle it? @HarshitT